# Not-standard shaped input field

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I need a text area field with an embedded button, like on this image:

```
 __________________________________
|Lorep ipsum lorep ipsum lorep ipsu|
|m lorep ipsum lorep ipsum lorep ip|
|sum lorep ipsum lorep ip _________|
|sum lorep ipsum lorep ip|   OK    |
|________________________|_________|
```

The text should flow around the button, without being hidden under it.

The only option I could imagine is custom `SVG` component with text and user action handlers, but that seems to be a bit overkill.

Any suggestion on simple (may be not perfect) approach for this task?

Comment: how about only showing the button on hovering the lower section of the text area?

Comment: How about automatically adding in a line break with javascript when near the button? (and just have the bottom positioned bottom right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally suck at this client-side stuff, but it seems to be possible with `contenteditable`.

```css
.input {
  width: 300px;
}

.submit {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='input' contenteditable=true>
    <div type='button' class='submit' contenteditable=false>Save</div>
    The text should flow around the button, without being hidden under it.

The only option I could imagine is custom SVG component with text and user action handlers, but that seems to be a bit overkill.

Any suggestion on simple (may be not perfect) approach for this task?
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Harry It has a subtle bug. But hey, it's a simple, not perfect approach :)

Comment: Yea, I too saw that just now (the positioning) but I think this probably is the closest that can be done.

Comment: @Harry: there's another one: going into edit mode and doing "cmd+a" (select all) also selects the button. And if you begin typing, you destroy it.

Comment: Ok, the destroy part I think can be overcome if you explicitly set `contenteditable = "false"` on the button. If I am not mistaken, it is a property that gets inherited by children. For the selection part, I think `-webkit-user-select: none;` (or with appropriate prefixes) should work :)

Comment: @Harry: yeah, thanks. This also disables select-all somehow. Anyway, this is the extent of my abilities here :)

Comment: You are welcome mate. We are all here to help each other :) And yeah, OP only wanted something closest to their expectation :)

Comment: This seems to be simplest and best solution. @jbutler gave similar answer, but this is faster, so answer is it. Btw a 3rd solution would be use of <map>, but for this case `contenteditable` div is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *quite* what you asked for, but maybe a different approach to take. I'm positioning the button at the bottom of a `contenteditable` div and only showing you it when you hover the lover section.

As i said, it's not a 'solution', more of a different approach of an issue.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow:auto;
}
.bot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bot:hover button {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="text" contenteditable="true">
    You can type in me! hover my lower section and you'll see the button!
  </div>
  <div class="bot">
    <button>OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Note**

This 'solution' could be tidied up, as most css styling is for 'extra bits', like overflow and transitions.

Comment: Why would anyone put a hidden OK button? :)

Comment: @ThePragmatick: Placing the bottom in the right bottom corner, whilst still able to 'see' behind it? It also allows you do 'select all'.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a textarea. But you can do it contenteditable div.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8xqwwxz/1/)**

Comment: @Harry To get the button to the bottom right and still maintain functionality is not possible.

Comment: I agree with that last point 100% and also with the first statement in your answer. If you had put this comment also in your answer I think the downvotes would not have happened.

Comment: I am removing my comments as now there are no downvotes and would also suggest you to add that last comment of yours to the answer so that people can know what you intend to say at one glance rather than having to scan through comments. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <div>
  <textarea name="" id="txt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

button{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 right:10px;
}
```

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

button{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:10px;
 right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea name="" id="txt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button>OK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The text goes under the button :)